# Can ZigBee API and ZigBee AT work together in the same network?

Tags: arduino-uno, xbee

I'm currently trying to make 3 arduinos talking to each other with ZigBee, and it's kinda working.
But I currently use AT mode on the Bees and it's a little bit harsh when I have to switch the destination address in the Coordinator of the network (1 Coordinator and 2 Routers)

Can I put the Coordinator in API mode (to make it easier to switch addresses with xbee-api for Arduino) but still be able to communicate with the AT routers and be able to send/receive data from them?

Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question has been answered on Stack Overflow, if you ask

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28765288/can-zigbee-api-and-zigbee-at-modules-work-together-in-the-same-network